Specific Enterprise ruling set for SonarLint extension in VSCode
I'm aware that on IntelliJ you can connect SonarLint extension to your company's sonarqube and import it's ruling set.
Is this possible on VSCode too?
If so, how can I do it?
I tried reading the VSCode extension documentation but found nothing about it.

create an issue at the extension repo

You can check the SonarLint official documentation which explains how to connect your SonarLint to your SonarQube in VS Code.
